# import sql database table into datatable

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

i am using this code below to allow me to go into my sql sever and get the data out and input the data into a datatable... but there is no data being added to the table and the table in the database has information in the table.

```
 // SQL Server Connection Strings
 sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog= " + databaseName + " ;Integrated Security=true";
 queryString = "select * from " + sqlTableName;
 using (var connection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
 using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, connection))
 {
      sqlDataTable.Clear();
      adapter.Fill(sqlDataTable);
 }
 return sqlDataTable;
```

Comment: no.. it jus does add nothing to the datatable.

Comment: What does your completed **connection string** look like? What is the value of `sqlTableName` here in your example??

Comment: when i inspect the data the count is 0

Comment: try by putting `try catch` block and see whether there is any exception

Comment: Have you actually checked the database to see if there is any data in the table you're trying to use?

Comment: Please show your complete related method and also how you are assigning it to your original DataTable. and also check your database as mentioned by Bridge.

Comment: just remove `using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, connection))` and put `var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, connection);` inside using block and check

Answer (score 1):

There could be four possible errors in your code

**1)** Try adding *schema name* (for example "dbo")

```
queryString = string.Format("select * from [dbo].['{0}']",sqlTableName);
```

**2)** *Unhandled Exception*

From MSDN [`DataTable.Clear()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clear.aspx)

> All rows in all tables are removed. An exception is generated if the table has any enforced child relations that would cause child rows to be orphaned.

I think at the point of `sqlDataTable.Clear()` your code is getting error (or somewhere else) which you are not handling by `try catch` block. so the datatable is empty.

**3)**  *database Table is empty*

**4)** Doesn't matter but try adding `connection.Open()`.

I cant say anything more until you show the complete code related to this function and how you are assigning this function(or method) to your original `DataTable`

Comment: According to the MSDN example, it's not necessary to explicitly call Open when using SqlDataAdapter - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx

Comment: when we use DataAdapter Does not require to use Open().

Comment: hmmm I dont know that. I am a beginner so I grab that as an error.

Comment: I am trying here.. if I dont know the answer I will delete this post :)

Comment: @user1776590 try by mentioning schema name with the calling table something like this `[dbo].[Table_Name]`

Answer (score 0):

Try to begin a transaction and commit it after you have added the data. I don't know much about C#, but I see a `BeginTransaction()` method on the `SqlConnection` object.

Comment: that was one of the first thing that i tried and dont really give much information..

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the "dont really give much information" part. Do you want me to provide a code sample in my answer? If you think it will help you, I'll gladly add one.